# libhostpolicy.so not found when trying to run a framework dependent build

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to build docker images for my asp.net 3.1 services. When I build self-contained I can use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps` base image just fine. However to improve build speed I am trying to use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime` or `aspnet` as my base image and copy the no-self-contained (framework dependent) publish output (from an earlier stage in docker build).

However when I try to run the container I see `A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/usr/share/dotnet'.`

I can reproduce this using the webapi sample project and the following Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic as build

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore --no-build -c Release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64 -o publish --self-contained false ./app.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /src/publish/. /app/

CMD [ "./app" ]
```

Also I can see the `libhostpolicy.so` bin does exist in `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.3/libhostpolicy.so`

Can you see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure what the cause of the error was but I can produce a container the same size as the problematic one that works properly by omitting the runtime from the dotnet commands as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic as build

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore --no-build -c Release -o publish ./app.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic 

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /src/publish/. /app/

CMD [ "./app" ]
```

If anyone knows why passing the RID caused a runtime dependency error I would be interested to know but for now I am happy